# Preserving indentation when inserting HTML from MySQL

Tags: mysql, html, indentation

I am using MySQL and PHP to populate parts of a site, often with HTML stored in a TEXT field. I like to keep my HTML indented so that the source is neat and easy to read, for example:

```
<body>
   <div>
      <p>Blahblah</p>
   </div>
</body>
```

However, when the HTML is pulled from MySQL, I end up with:

```
<body>
   <div>
<p>Blahblahblah</p>
   </div>
</body>
```

This is quite ugly when there is a large amount of HTML being inserted into a DIV that is significantly indented. How can I stop this from happening? FYI, I use wordwrap() to keep each line from being too long.

Comment: Why do you care so much how your HTML source looks like? Nobody is going to appreciate that your HTML is all neatly indented, and for debugging purposes there is validator, tidy and your favorite browser's web developer tool. Don't waste your time.

Comment: Debugging is often easier if code is readable. I wouldn't spend a *lot* of time formatting, but if everything is on one continuous line, it's a mess to read. Tidy can help though.

Comment: @Tomalak so you're saying it's not important that the Stack Overflow system preserves whitespace in code blocks?

Comment: I'm guessing you want to do this for ease of debugging the output? Why not use Firebug on FF or IE 8's built in debugging capability? Both do a Tidy to make it easier to read.

Comment: @Peter: Hm? What's *that* got to do with it? There is relevant whitespace (generally, whitespace that's part of actual data, like code for example) and then there is irrelevant whitespace that serves no purpose other than making yourself feel good about how "view source" looks like in the browser. The latter is a waste of time. At least when taken too seriously.

Comment: @Tomalak A waste of time *to you*.  Regardless of its objective value, subjectively this what Benjamin wants.  And regardless of all that, there *is* a software-related issue to be solved here.  Even if it wasn't relevant, I think I'd want to know if there was some routine chewing up whitespace somewhere in *my* application.

Comment: @Peter: Of course this is subjective, no argument there. Also, everybody can do what they want with their time. ;) I was just suspecting attention being given to the wrong thing here and wanted to give another perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could indent the lines manually with PHP:

```
$tabs = 4;
echo str_repeat(chr(9), $tabs) . str_replace(chr(10), chr(10) . str_repeat(chr(9), $tabs), $text);
```

You can also remove the first `str_repeat(chr(9), $tabs) .` if you don't want the first line to get indented.

Comment: Brilliant! Got it to do exactly what I wanted it to do by passing $text through a wordwrap() first, then through your solution, and finally echoing $text in the DIV. As for the folks who were arguing above, why not do this? It makes me happy LOL Thanks, Dragory!

Answer (score 0):

With which datatype are you storing the HTML in the database?  I suspect you are using VARCHAR, but BLOB would be better.

A simple fix would be to use spaces rather than tabs in the HTML.  It seems the database is ignoring the \t character.